# Simpson's rule in C - Incorrect answer

Tags: c, area

I have written a program to calculate the area under the curve for function:
f = tan(x). I made a few fixes (i.e. dim must be greater than 61) so the program compiles and runs but outputs the wrong answer! I am thinking the error is in the for loops that are summing up the Tan[j]s but not sure where...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

//Question 3a. Create a program that calculates the area under the curve of:
// y = tan(x) from 0 --> pi/3


//TODO: Declare function to change degrees to radians as in Ex. 3 of practical

float degtorad(float arg);
float pi = 3.1415927;

int main(void) {

 int i, j, sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;
 int dim; //Loop index, Counter, Array dimension
 float a, b, rad, h, Tan[dim], area ; //Return value of the function, Result array, Area, Coefficient
 b = (float)(pi)/(float)(3);
 h = ((float)(b - a))/((float)(dim - 1));

 printf("\nPlease input a value for the step size.\n");
 scanf("%d", &dim);
 //TODO: Get table of tan as in Ex. 3
 j=0;
 for (i=0; i<=60; i++) {
    rad = degtorad(i);
    Tan[j] = tan(rad);
    j=j+1;
    }

 /*
 TODO: Calculate the are using Simpson's rule. Simpson's rule is the combination of the 
 trapezoid rule and the midpoint rule so different steps apply depending on if the step is 
 even or odd. */ 


//Check if dimension is odd
 if (dim%2 == 1) {
    for (i =  0; i < dim - 1; i++) {
        //Rule for even number. This is where the trapezoid rule is applied. 
        if (i%2 == 0) {
        sum1 = sum1 + Tan[i];
        }
        //Else is for the odd iterations that come from the midpoint rule. 
        else { 
        sum2 = sum2 + Tan[i];
        }
    }
    //Calculating the area using Simpson's rule.

    area = (h/3) * ((tan(a)) + (4 * sum2) + (2 * sum1) + (tan(b)));
    printf("\nThe area under the curve is: %1.8f\n", area); 
    }

    return 0;

}

//TODO: Definition of the function as in Ex. 3

float degtorad(float arg) {
    return( (pi * arg)/180.0 );

}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: A segmentation fault is typically caused by writing into memory you don't own; for example, writing past the end of an array...

Comment: Or reading from memory you don't own.

Comment: I'm not getting the segmentation fault anymore... the program is running now just outputting the wrong answer. Possibly a problem with the math more than the program?

Answer (score 3):

You declare `Tan` with size `dim`, which you didn't initialize before using it:

```
int dim; // dim isn't initialized
float Tan[dim]; // array Tan of size ?
```

So, `dim` is undefined and so is the size of `Tan`.

Seeing as you get `dim` from the user, you first need to call

```
scanf("%d", &dim);
```

and then declare `Tan` with it:

```
scanf("%d", &dim);
float Tan[dim];
```

**ADDIT**: However, your `for`-loop after getting the user input runs with `i` and `j` from 0 to 60 (inclusive), regardless of the user's input. You want to loop this from 0 to `dim` (exclusive):

```
for(i = 0; i < dim; i++){
```

And, since `i` and `j` have the same value every iteration, you don't need `j`:

```
    rad = degtorad(i);
    Tan[i] = tan(rad);
}
```

Your compiler should have warned you about this, if it didn't enable all warnings (usually with the `-Wall` option). If it did: **never ignore compiler warnings!**

---

In addition I get the following warning when acutally compiling your program:

```
In function 'main':
19:7: warning: 'a' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
      h = ((float)(b - a))/((float)(dim - 1));
```

Comment: Also (to OP): Learn how to use a debugger. By spending 5 minutes learning how to debug this in gdb, you'll enjoy it for a lifetime.

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer yes you can: C has [variable-length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) since C99.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for pointing that out!  Looks really wrong in my eyes :)

Comment: Ok I moved the user input to before the Tan[dim] but I'm still getting the same error.... any ideas?

Comment: @user3306583: Make sure that `dim` is at least 61, since you are trying to store that many numbers in your `for` loop.

Comment: Ok, I got it to run except now it's just outputting the wrong answer... I know I've put simpson's rule in correctly (checked through a few times although maybe I'm missing something). I can't see what else is wrong though...